# What are Clan Points?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was looking at my clan's information, and I noticed a section called Clan Points. At first I thought it was the total of all clan member's Trophies, but that's not it. So what are Clan Points and how are they calculated?

**NOTE:** When I get home I will make the question more narrow and say where to find said section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Clash of Clans Wikia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clans):

> The clan ranking is based on the number of trophies of its members. This value is weighted according to the following table.

For reference, here is the weighting used:

```
1-10    50%     
11-20   25%  
21-30   12%   
31-40   10%  
41-50   3%
```

So it is calculated by the amount of trophies in a weighted system instead of a simple total.